# Continuous random variable density function

Tags: calculus, probability

[image]

I'm confused as why the solution for (a)

[image]

Why does it go from $k$ integral from -3 to 3 of $(9 - x^2)dx$ to $2k$ times the  integral from $0$ to $3$ of  $(9 - x^2)dx$?

Why wouldn't you be able to just solve it by taking the integral from -3 to 3, why do you have to make the lower bound 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you look at the function $(9 - x^2)$, you will notice that it is an even function. Which means that $\int_{-t}^t (9 - x^2) = \int_{0}^t 2(9 - x^2)$
(think about how the graph of it looks like. Since the left and right side of the graph is symmetric, their area under the curve is exactly the same. Now haveing that said, even if you don't do this step of changing the bound to zero, just evaluating the original integral would give you the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is an even function. Have a look at this [figure](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9-x%5E2)